# Wrap items only if they are two certain elements

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="group">
    <label>Text: </label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div class="group">
    <label>Text: </label>
</div>
```

I want to wrap `label + input` inside another div wrapper like this:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <label>Text: </label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="group">
    <label>Text: </label>
</div>
```

I tried with this:

```
$(".group").each(function() {
    $(this).find("label, input").wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
});
```

the problem is that even when is there only `label` inside the `div.group` is wrapped.
I want to wrap label and input if they are on div.group, **but if there is only input or label do not wrap**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more alternative:

```
$(".group").each(function() {
    var hasLabel = $(this).children("label").length;
    var hasTxtInput = $(this).children("input[type='text']").length;

    if (hasLabel && hasTxtInput)
        $(this).find("label, input").wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/bcyho07v/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly also after I add another element to the `wrapper`.

Answer (score 4):

Without using each:

```
// get the input after the label
var $input = $('.group label + input');

// we know that before $input there is a label
$input.add($input.prev()).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c8wq67d4/1/

---

Since you can have several `.group` with a set of `label + input` children, this solution is more correct:

```
var $input = $('.group label + input');
$input.add($input.prev()).parent().wrapInner('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
```

The previous solution was doing a `wrapAll` to all set (see PeterKA fiddle).
The point is to `wrapInner` each parent and not `wrapAll` of them.

http://jsfiddle.net/c8wq67d4/4/

Comment: @PeterKA Thanks for pointing that out. I made a correction for cases when `$input` returns several elements.

Comment: Thank you so much @JoseRuiSantos but if I want to add another element to the `.wrapper` then your example doesn't works. The example of @jyrkim is good because if I add another element to the `wrapper` it continues to work.

Comment: @Fuiba If you are talking about adding another element between `label` and `input`, then all you need to do is change the selector to `$('.group label ~ input')`. http://jsfiddle.net/c8wq67d4/5/

Answer (score 3):

One approach that I'd suggest:

```js
// iterate over each of the <input> elements using each():
$('input').each(function() {
  // find the previous <label> element sibling (if it exists),
  // add the <input> back to the selection and wrap both in the <div>:
  $(this).prev('label').addBack().wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group">
  <label>Text:</label>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div class="group">
  <label>Text:</label>
</div>
```

References:

- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/).

Comment: This wraps any set of `label + input` siblings, regardless of their parent (if any) is a `.group` or not. I think the OP wants to search for those elements only inside `.group`.

Comment: Thank you @DavideThomas and Thanks @JoseRuiSantos. As I said I want to wrap label and input in a div if they are on `.group`.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
$('.group:has(label+input)').each(function() {
    $(this).children('label,input').wrapAll( $('<div/>',{class:'wrapper'}) );
});
```

```js
$('.group:has(label+input)').each(function() {
  $(this).children('label,input').wrapAll( $('<div/>',{class:'wrapper'}) );
});
//output new html
var newHTML = $('<div/>').html( $('.group').clone() ).html();
$('pre.out').text( newHTML );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group">
    <label>Text: </label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>

<div class="group">
    <label>Text: </label>
</div>

<div class="group">
    <label>Text: </label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div class="group">
    <label>Text: </label>
</div>


<h1>NEW HTML</h1>
<pre class="out"></pre>
```